# Is it possible to pass options (not params) to a function in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, scripting

It would look something like the following:

```
my_functions(){
  while getopts ":a" Option
    do
      case $Option in
        a ) echo "a" ;;
        * ) ;;
      esac
    done
}
```

Then you would call it with:

```
function -ab
```

Is this possible or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It can be done, but you need to keep track of your *global* variables. What happens when you test it?

Comment: BTW, You can drop the $ on `$OPTIND - 1`, and the two variables at the top, as they aren't used.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: It returns command not found. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention: `function` is a shell keyword.  For the test, rename it to `f()` instead.   The `function` keyword originates from `ksh` for an alternative function definition syntax.

Comment: Can't believe it. I created the function on the inside of another function. Also, this alias="gedit ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc" wasn't sourcing after leaving gedit. After this corrections it works now.

Comment: I've put the keyword function for readability. The real function name is different on the script. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but this specific example suffered from a poor choice for the function name.  This should do it:

```
f(){

while getopts ":a" Option
do
    case $Option in
    a ) echo "a" ;;
    * ) ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

}
```